# Ubuntu 16.04 nvme problems continue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvme

I was recently watching netflix on ubuntu when all of a sudden the entire system froze. I couldn't do anything, the system was just stuck so I had to do a hard shutdown. After that the ubuntu loader seems to have vanished. The problem for me is that I was working on a C++ project which I didn't back up before the crash. Long story short, here's a screen shot
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOLnp.jpg)

I found something online and was trying to follow the instructions, but that didn't work out for me. Anyway I can get back into ubuntu or get it to load again? The drive for some reason was listed twice in BIOS, one seems to load grub the other would actually load the dual boot menu where you get the option to load ubuntu windows advanced system options etc. I just need to get my files off the drive if anyone could help me please, thank you.

Here are my specs. I'm using a laptop Clevo P7xxTM1 with

- i7 8700
- 32GB RAM
- gtx 1070 GPU
- 2x WD Black NVMe m.2 512gb (one for ubuntu and one for windows)

Comment: Have the same problem here with Lubuntu 17.10 cpu i7 8700T and 512GB Samsung 960 Pro PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD.  I do wunder how you use ubuntu 16.04 with the i7 8700T as i understood 17.10 is needed at least.

Comment: I have a clevo which supports the desktop version of the 8700 that's why I have no issue loading 16.04 on here. I had to reinstall my ubuntu again. As a windows user I was installing antivirus on Ubuntu, but this time I didn't and haven't had problems with the drive or booting. Not sure if that helps you, but I would like to know what exactly is causing this issue and if there's a solution too.